# How to start dota2 on ubuntu in an unprivileged lxc container, since steam starts dota2 now in a runtime sandbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

Since the latest update, steam starts some linux games in a sandbox. If you have steam in an lxc container, so it does not install libs in your main OS or you want to isolate it from you work files, dota2 crashes, since steam wants to start a container in your lxc container which fails. This is a pretty specific usecase, but maybe other people have encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can type in this code or copy it into a bash script:

```
export STEAM_RUNTIME=0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#add this line on radeon cards
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota\ 2\ beta/game/dota.sh -vulkan
```